# What was this 90's movie about 'God'?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching this movie on TV when I was a kid. It must be around 1997-98, but I'm not sure. Of course, the movie itself must be older.

It was about a strange, otherworldly tower-like structure suddenly appearing on a desert-like place (probably somewhere around Middle-East, again not sure). It had healing powers around its surrounding area. One of the main characters had a cancer (lung cancer maybe) and when he came around this structure he was gradually healed.

I remember a specific line in the movie that goes: (Wording might not be the same.)
"This thing might be what we call The God for thousands of years."

Once it was discovered, there was a military occupation around and they were arguing about whether or not to destroy while main characters were trying to save it. At some point, they were going inside the structure.

I could not find the movie. Maybe I misremember some things.
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the 2001 film "[Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(film))".

> Alarmed by the electromagnetic phenomenon and under request of the
>   government of Bhutan, the American NSA launches a military and
>   scientific reconnaissance operation on site, led by Dr. K.C. Czaban
>   (Stephanie Niznik) with the technical assistance of terminally ill
>   engineer Mason Rand (David Keith), picked up on the Mexican border in
>   time for the mission. The team finds the artifact suspended in the air
>   and object of veneration from the natives, who call it the Torus and
>   consider it a gift from the gods with extraordinary healing
>   properties.

[image]

Comment: Yes. It is definitely this one. Thank you so much. It seems I was wrong about date and some other things.

Comment: @durmus - No worries. You've given a pretty good description of a very very bad film. Might I suggest though, that instead of watching this dreck again, you might like to watch something that isn't crap. "Sphere", "Event Horizon" and the remake of "Solaris" all deal with quite similar themes... :-)

Comment: The NSA launches a mission on the request of Bhutan? I can only guess the screenwriter is not an American.

Comment: @Valorum Is it bad bad or so-bad-it-is-good bad?

Comment: @Édouard - There are many films that are so bad they're good. This film, alas is merely so bad it's bad.

Comment: @Valorum I personally prefer the turn of phrase "so bad it's terrible".

Comment: @ToddWilcox for something like this, I'm sure the intelligence agencies would jump to officially put their feet there at the slightest petition (and unofficially, they probably already had some agents there).