# Sci-fi B movie similar to Arrival

Tags: story-identification

The first thing that came to mind when I saw *Arrival* was "I already saw that!"

I remember that I've seen a somewhat B-ish movie, I only remember the plot was similar to *Arrival*, a huge black monolith-like ship arrives, it is vertical, hangs in the air just like in *Arrival*, and they go in to investigate its secret.

That is all I can remember, I haven't really paid attention, but now I've seen *Arrival* I really want to find out what it was.

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question

Comment: Gigantic hanging monolith thing? It must be [Epoch](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/128904/20774)

Comment: I had the same feeling when I was watching Arrival. But I ended up deciding it was because I'd begun to perceive time non-linearly.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - I'd rather aliens invaded than have to watch Epoch again.

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn
We cannot vote for Duplicate unless both have accepted answers.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots sorry, missed the whole thread on duplicates for IDs even when obvious. Retracting vote

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the made-for-TV film [Epoch](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0233657/). It featured a gigantic  black monolith-like ship that hangs upside-down in the air. The main characters go inside it to investigate.

[image]

Comment: I think that is the correct answer. This should be it. Thanks

Comment: @Mtom - Let us know when you're sure.